# Reversing an LCG

Tags: random-functions

I'm having a hard time finding an answer to this. I've found several places that discuss it, but they do a very poor job of helping me (specifically me, maybe I'm dumb) understand what they're doing. For the below example, the solution should work for ***c=0*** as well as any other whole number. I've shown values just to be clear that I'm talking about the same equation in the same state, but going forward and in reverse.

I have an LCG: ***Xn = X×a + c % m*** (I do believe this is full cycle)

- For: ***a=67***, ***c=0***, ***m=101***, ***X=1***
- ***X<sub>n</sub> = ((1×67) + 0) % 101***
- ***X<sub>n</sub> = 67***

If I were instead to know the values as follows...

- For: ***a=67***, ***c=0***, ***m=101***, ***X<sub>n</sub> = 67***
- ***67 = ((X×67) + 0) % 101***
- ***X = ?***

... how would I rearrange to solve for ***X***? I am assuming ***X*** could only be at max ***m***.

Comment: In your example, isn't it trivial that $X=1$?

Comment: But your $X_n\equiv aX+c\bmod m$ should be $X_n\equiv aX_{n-1}+c\bmod m$, right?

Comment: To both your questions, yes, I was trying to make sure I was clear that I was looking at the same equation in both cases, just with different variables revealed.

Comment: Do you know n? [1 more to go]

Comment: @rain1 I corrected it. I meant "Xn" as one term. It's now properly formatted. I added some more formatting too for, I hope, better ease of reading.

Comment: I've been trying to read through some papers people have suggested elsewhere, but I can't get anything to work. For instance, this paper -> https://www.cc.gatech.edu/computing/pads/PAPERS/rc-pads99.pdf on page 5 shows how to get the inverse of ***a*** for reversibility, but when I try that method out I do not get my previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ a\ $ and $\ m\ $ are relatively prime (which is the case for $\ a=67\ $ and $\ m=101\ $, because both are prime), then there is always an integer $\ b\ $ between $1$ and $100$ inclusive such that $\ ba\equiv1\pmod{m}\ $.  If you then multiply the congruence
$$
X_n\equiv aX_{n-1}+c\pmod{m}
$$
by $\ b\ $, you get
\begin{align}
bX_n &\equiv baX_{n-1}+bc \pmod{m}\\
&\equiv X_{n-1}+bc \pmod{m}\ ,
\end{align}
or
$$
X_{n-1}\equiv bX_n+d\pmod{m}\ ,
$$
where $\ d\ $ is the remainder of $\ (m-b)c\pmod{m}\ $.

For $\ a=67\ $ and $\ m=101\ $, $\ b\ $ turns out to be $\ 98\ $, so the reverse of your equation is
$$
X_{n-1}\equiv98X_n \pmod{m}\ .
$$
More generally, the usual way of finding the number $\ b\ $ is to use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to obtain $\ b\ $ and $\ e\ $ satisfying the equation $\ ab+me=\gcd(a,m)$ ($=1\ $ if $\ a\ $ and $\ m\ $ are relatively prime).

Comment: For my own knowledge, to be clear, ***b*** is the inverse of ***a*** as derived from the extended Euclidean algorithm, right? I took a look at that last night and again this morning (I made a comment of it in my post above) and couldn't get it to work. I'll take a look at your solution here. I super appreciate the help. This one is breaking my brain. :P

Comment: Yes! It worked. I think I saw where I went wrong. I didn't multiply ***c*** by ***b*** when I was trying to before. I do this as a hobby. Passed up trying for a degree in programming or math or something, for [admittedly well paying] work but I try to keep at it. I really appreciate it!